# Meteor Restivus : Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response

Tags: javascript, mongodb, rest, meteor

I tried to update a record(mongo DB) using the endpoint `PUT` generated by restivus in meteor. It is working with the 'localhost' address. When instead of 'localhost' used the ip address it returned the following error.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.44:3000/api/v1/posts/HBw6uWkzScivNj9Er. Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

I read their documents, but couldn't find a solution. If anybody faced the similar situation and solved the issue, please share your solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would notice that when your browser's address bar shows `localhost` url, the `localhost` request works. But if your browser address bar shows `192.168.2.44` (assuming it is your machine), the localhost url will stop working and the ip address url will work. Browsers will not allow making an `XMLHttpRequest` or an `ajax` request to a different domain name. In this case your ip address and `localhost` are different domains, even though they point to same computer. Still browsers will not allow it due to Cross Origin request policy.

Whenever you are making an ajax request, its best to not mention a domain at all. This will default the browser to make requests on the same domain which is loaded. Simply substitute your url with `/api/v1/posts/HBw6uWkzScivNj9Er` and you will ensure it always works.

I recommend reading the following MDN article for a complete understanding of Cross Origin policy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @DeepakJose You are welcome. Consider upvoting the answer.